# VSTS: "You are not allowed to perform this task because of the permissions in the Azure AD. Please contact your directory admin"

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Has anyone else encountered this issue when trying to add additional users to a repo in VSTS (via the web GUI)? (We have not exceeded the 5-user limit.)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you validate your permissions in Azure AD?

Comment: Which specific permissions do you need in Azure AD to add users to a VSTS project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Azure Ad you need the permission "global admin or privileged role admin **"to add the user"**

If you have VSTS account then for adding users into VSTS you required **VSTS project collection administrator or account owner permissions**

You can refer the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/manage-azure-active-directory-groups-vsts?view=vsts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?toc=%2Fvsts%2Forganizations%2Faccounts%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fvsts%2Forganizations%2Faccounts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts#add-a-user-or-group-to-a-security-group